# I cannot run firebase emulators on fresh install. Getting ' SyntaxError: Unexpected string: re"use strict"; '

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I followed the tutorial to set up Firebase Functions with Typescript at
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

However, when I run `npm run serve` or `firebase emulators:start`, emulators won't start, but I'm getting the following error:

```
[2023-03-25T09:04:16.875Z] /Users/username/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.11.4/server/server.js:569
        re"use strict";
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried deleting the cache folder, with no effect. In the file server.js, the relevant lines are:

```
function createDebug(namespace) {
    function debug2() {
      if (!debug2.enabled)
        re"use strict";
```

Installed versions of the relevant libraries are:

```
firebase --version
11.25.1

node -v
v16.19.1

npm -v
8.19.3

java --version
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 19.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 19.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)

tsc --version
Version 5.0.2
```

I'm out of ideas what to try, or what to reinstall. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

I tried reinstalling all libraries, set up a new firebase project, installed the correct node version, reinstalled jdk. Was expecting emulators to run.

Comment: I think you should point to jdk 11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue as you. I raised the following [ticket](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools-ui/issues/933) on Firebase. Was facing this on MacOS (and Linux), but I assumed it's an issue with the Node version I was using (not being LTS).

### Issue:

After some investigation the following elements are the cause of the issue.

- Node Version - using an incompatible version of Node. Change to Node LTS version.
- Java Version - using an incompatible version of Java. Change to use compatible version e.g. Java version 11

### Resolution:

To resolve it I amended the host environment to use compatible versions as described above. The Node + Java components are the ones that are important.

On my device, the following setting allowed the Emulator UI to run successfully.

```
node - v16.19.1
npm - 8.19.3
firebase - 11.25.1
java openjdk - 11.0.18
```

I then deleted the machine cache located:

```
~/.cache/firebase
```

Then restart the emulator

```
firebase emulators:start
```

- The firebase emulator components should download again
- The emulator starts up without the error.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue

```
[2023-03-25T09:04:16.875Z] /Users/username/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui- 
v1.11.4/server/server.js:569
    re"use strict";
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I fixed it with a flag:
In firebase.json, set

```
"ui": {
  "enabled": false      ← SET TO FALSE
},
```

It Works for me!
Regards

Comment: Interesting! Thank you, this lets me run emulators now as well. I'll keep looking for a solution that lets us keep using emulator ui.

Comment: Worked for me too!
No UI, but thats a problem for another day...

Comment: Thank you, just to extend this answer, the full config is:
"emulators":{
    "ui": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }

Answer (score 4):

Here is the copy-paste solution from Richard Rose's bug ticket:

```
brew install node@16
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin:$PATH"
rm -rf ~/.cache/firebase
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase emulators:start
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. Important to stress to clear up the cache with `rm -rf ~/.cache/firebase` to make sure it works. I was missing this step somehow.

Answer (score 3):

None of the suggested solutions worked for me, I had to manually unzip `~/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.11.5.zip`

I found this solution [on the github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools-ui/issues/933#issuecomment-1509925965), where someone commented:

> Only thing that worked for me was to go to ~/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.11.5 and manually unzip ui-v1.11.5.zip there.